# Left tree is not compatible with right tree

Tags: xml, lua

I am having an error when putting a data from database to XML.
Error is `Left tree elem1 is not compatible with right tree REC_ID`.

[image]

let's say these are the values on my database

[image]

I want to put the `REC_ID` to `<elem1>` and `EmpRecID` to `<elem2>` and so on.
I am thinking to use "For" loop statement so I could fetch the data where `REC_ID = 123` and `REC_ID = 221`. so my expected output will be below:

```
<ParentXML> 
  <myXml> 
    <elem1>123</elem1> -- value comes from the first REC_ID 
    <elem2>123</elem2> -- value comes from first EmpRecID 
  </myXml> 
  <myXml> 
    <elem1>221</elem1> -- value comes from second REC_ID 
    <elem2>222</elem2> -- value comes from second EmpRecID 
  </myXml> 
</ParentXML>
```

I currently removed the `ParentXML` so it won't come with the loop.
Please advise what I can do on this loop.

Comment: Note: Next time you ask a question, Please don't take a screenshot of the code. Please post the code directly to your question so It would be answered/addressed more faster and efficiently. For more info, please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where do `db`, `conn`, and `xml` come from? Lua is not just used for databases; it is used for many, many things, and `db`, `conn`, and `xml` are not part of Lua; they are part of whatever framework you are using. Please don't be afraid to let me know if you aren't sure what I mean by framework.

Comment: Hi NetherGranite, Thanks for your response. I am using Iguana by interfaceware.